# How to add a project to a existing EAR in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

How can I add a new java project to a existing EAR in eclipse?

I used `project references`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered!

In EAR > right-click > properties > Java EE Module Dependences

Comment: Its changed to EAR > right-click > Properties > Project Refernces

Answer (score 17):

In Eclipse 4.4 Luna, right click on the ear > properties > Deployment Assembly. Click Add and select the project you would like to add.

Comment: this one worked for me! I'm using Eclipse Kepler thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In EAR > right-click > properties > Project References 
Select the project